# How to view 2seperate forms by clicking two different buttons

Tags: php

I did the php code with two buttons in **1st php file**.Now i am trying to do in **another php file, by clicking the button one seperate form is to be open and by clicking the other button  another seperate form is to get open**. But i dont know how to do this.

```
<input type="submit" name="question" value="question" />
<input type="submit" name="answer" value="answer" />
```

please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how your form are **opended**. Can you explain more?

Comment: Ya sure. The form with two buttons are in **one php file**. By clicking the button if it is **question** it is linked to another php file, a seperate form with some textbox field have to get open. By clicking the answer button the another form with some answer fields  have to get open. The two fors with some text fields will be in same php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
<input type="submit" name="question" value="question" onclick="file1.php" />
<input type="submit" name="answer" value="answer"  onclick="file2.php" />
```

**Method 2**

```
<form action="file1.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="question" value="question" /></form>

<form action="file2.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="answer" value="answer" /></form>
```

If your using a single file then keep a hidden variable on form and check the variable value on the next page and take nessery action. 
ex:

```
    <form action="a.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Var1" value="question"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="question" value="question" />
</form>

    <form action="a.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Var1" value="answer"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="answer" value="answer" /></form>
```

**a.php**

```
check POST['var1']=="question"{
//do something
}
check POST['var1']=="answer"{
//do something
}
```

I dont know if there is any bettr method, but you can solve like this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i'm using a single php file for both forms. I'm not using like **file1.php** and **file2.php**. I am using only one php file like a.php.

Comment: Ya it is more helpful for me. Bt nw i was supposed to do everything in a single php file i.e) a.php. please tell me how to do this.

Comment: @tweety use the same way  that i told use 'hidden' variable  and check   the value do wt you wand

Comment: ok, Thanks Abin. I did wt i need with the sample code given by you. Thanks again.

Comment: Please tell me,how to write the javascript. The same two buttons i'm having. i've to write the seperate functions for both buttons in javascript with one **onsubmit=return validate()** as common for both. How to write seperate javascript for both functions with one validate function. please tell me.